# How would a dev make a JTable LOOK editable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing an application that has a JTable, and an edit button that sets the current selected row to be editable. Then once the user is done altering the data, they can click the edit button again (with text that now says "Save") to save the data.

The problem is though, when I set a row to be editable, there isn't a visible difference. I could add some code to the renderer to draw the editable cells a little differently, but I don't know what the proper way to make a cell look editable is. Change the color? Make it look like a JTextField? What's the standard method?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could call [`JTable#editCellAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editCellAt(int,%20int)) to start the editing process for the first column of the selected row.  But beyond that, it comes do to your own needs.  Given it's the `CellRenderer`s responsibility to render the state of the row, then, yes, I might suggest using it.  You could also try changing the color of the `selectionBackground` color, but you'd need to be able to change it back again if the user changes rows before the click "save"...

Answer (score 0):

Really this is a user interface design question, not a programming one.

To do what you want you need to supply an appropriate cell renderer with the changes you desire but you will need to decide on your own settings. One option might just be to look at the difference between an editable and non-editable text area and apply those to all the cells on the table. This may be as simple as setting the renderers to disabled for any read-only rows.